# Left Join in Linq with nullable references

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two tables, one for MainCourse and one for SubCourse.
The MainCourse doesn't necessarily need a SubCourse, thus there are null values in the SubCourse table with no link to the MainCourse ID....

I have to create a left join in linq... I can create a normal join, but the problem is that when I run the join only data will show which has both a MainCourse and a SubCourse. I need to show the MainCourse which does not have SubCourse as well..

This is what I done:

Brings back only data which has both a MainCourse and SubCourse

```
                    var query = (from mc in context.SkillAssessCourseMains
                         join sc in context.SkillAssessCourseSubs
                         on mc.ID equals sc.MainCourseRef
                         select new
                         {
                             sc.ID,
                             mc.CourseName,
                             sc.SubCourseName
                         }).DefaultIfEmpty().ToList();
```

Trying to modify this to bring back all data gives me an error of : The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type. (Below code)

```
    var query = (from mc in context.SkillAssessCourseMains
                         from sc in context.SkillAssessCourseSubs.Where(sc => sc.MainCourseRef == mc.ID).DefaultIfEmpty()
                         select new
                         {
                             sc.ID,
                             mc.CourseName,
                             sc.SubCourseName
                         }).ToList();
```

I know the error is as a result that there is no link to a submodule..

I also tried this:

```
    var query = (from mc in context.SkillAssessCourseMains
                         join sc in context.SkillAssessCourseSubs
                         on mc.ID equals sc.MainCourseRef into results
                         from r in results.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         select new
                         {
                             r.ID,
                             mc.CourseName,
                             r.SubCourseName
                         }).ToList();
```

which also gave me an error of: The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

The tables are designed as:

```
    MainCourse: ID, CourseName
    SubCourse: ID, SubCourseName, MainCourseRef
```

Can anybody please point me in the right direction or tell me what I'm doing wrong? Any help will be greatly appreciated....

EDIT

Example of data:

MainCourse table:

```
    ID      MainCourseName
    1       Health & Safety
    2       Customer Care
```

SubCourse table:

```
    ID      SubCourseName      MainCourseRef
    1       Introduction       1
    2       First Aid          1
    3       SHE rep course     1
```

Thus, the data that I want to bring back is:

```
    MainCourseName    SubCourseName
    Healt & Safety    Introduction
    Healt & Safety    First Aid
    Healt & Safety    SHE rep course
    Customer Care     NULL
```

An ID as well, but could be either from the SubCourse or MainCourse table....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error because mc.ID is int,but sc.MainCourseRef is not int .

If MainCourseRef is type "MainCourse" then try this

```
on mc.ID equals sc.MainCourseRef.ID
```

**EDIT**

```
var query = (from mc in context.SkillAssessCourseMains
                         join sc in context.SkillAssessCourseSubs.Where(x=>x.MainCourseRef!=null)
                         on mc.ID equals sc.MainCourseRef into results
                         from r in results.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         select new
                         {
                             r.ID,
                             mc.CourseName,
                             r.SubCourseName
                         }).ToList();
```

Comment: MainCourseRef is an integer value (foreign key in db (SubCourse table) to ID of MainCourse table).... The problem is that some MainCourseRef is null in the SubCourse table as not all Main Courses have a SubCourse....

Comment: Then try this `on mc.ID equals sc.MainCourseRef==null?0:sc.MainCourseRef`

Comment: thanks very much, in addition to the change, I took mc.ID instead of r.ID as well... thanks for your help